# Is there a modular magic system which allows players to compose their own spells

Tags: dnd-5e, metamagic

I would like some more player creativity in my magic, where the players can design their own spells. I was about to write my own system, but was wondering if there is anything out there.

We are playing a custom D&D 5e campaign, but a system from another setting could be adapted if necessary.
Ideally, a modular magic system would:

- require some resources to fuel the magic
- would depend on creativity and finding new ways to cast spells for the players

I have searched multiple sources, and could not find anything suiting.

What does rpg recommend?

Comment: How detailed do you want the system to be? Would something super-generic like Fate also fulfill your requirements?

Comment: Do you want something easy to slot into D&D 5E, or are you willing to do some customization to get things to fit reasonably well?